# Watch for updated properties in Wicket

Tags: internationalization, wicket

In my current project we need to implement a way for texters to manage the wicket messages/internationalization via upload of property files.

Also see this question: [Administrating internationalized wicket applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140429/administrating-internationalized-wicket-applications)

As suggested there, I've implemented a custom `IStringResourceLoader` and added it at the beginning of the StringResourceLoader list to override any properties already in place:

```
getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(0, new CustomStringResourceLoader());
```

This however is not enough, because updates can happen and need to be loaded at runtime. StringResources are cached by wicket and updated only when the `ResourceWatcher` is triggered.

I found where Wicket adds the string resources to the watcher: the `PropertiesFactory` in the settings. The method to add a resource to the watcher is `addToWatcher(...)`. However this method is protected and also the whole setup suggests this is used for development purposes and not for production.

I managed to use this method by extending `PropertiesFactory` and effectively creating a custom version to add to settings:

```
getResourceSettings().setPropertiesFactory(new CustomPropertiesFactory(getResourceSettings()));
getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(Duration.seconds(1));
```

So my Question is: I feel this is quite the circuitious solution. Is there another way to watch for changing properties files?

Comment: Instead of polling for updated files, we trigger an update when the file is uploaded. i.e.- create an interface to update the file instead of allowing backend access to the file structure.  I am not sure what you mean by 'texters' though, so perhaps this scheme won't work for you.

Comment: Texters: the people who provide the localized strings, these have to be deployed separate from the wicket application at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem:

```
getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(0, new CustomResourceLoader());
getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add(new Path("/pathToResources"));
getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(Duration.seconds(1));
```

This inserts my `CustomResourceLoader` at the beginning of the list so all properties are first checked there.

The added `Path` tells the `PropertiesFactory` to look for resources in a given arbitrary directory outside of wicket.

I needed custom names for my resource files as well, I realized this in the `CustomResourceLoader`:

```
public String loadStringResource(final Class<?> clazz, final String key, final Locale locale, final String style, final String variation) {
    final String myResourceFilename = createCustomResourceFileName(locale); 
    final IPropertiesFactory pF = Application.get().getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory();
    final org.apache.wicket.resource.Properties props = pF.load(clazz, myResourceFilename);
    ...
}
```

When using the `PropertiesFactory` to load the files, it adds them to the internal `IModificationWatcher` automatically.

It turns out that part of the problem was, that the resource files are in a non-standard encoding. This can be fixed by adding a special `IPropertyLoader` to the `PropertiesFactory` in the settings:

```
((PropertiesFactory) getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory()).getPropertiesLoaders().add(0,
            new UtfPropertiesFilePropertiesLoader("properties", "your-favorite-encoding"));
```