# External wicket property file

Tags: wicket

I was looking on the following question and would be interested how this might work in wicket 1.5:
[Administrating internationalized wicket applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140429/administrating-internationalized-wicket-applications)

[Watch for updated properties in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219243/watch-for-updated-properties-in-wicket)

Would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Please, can you be more concrete and explain, what exactly do you want to achieve using Wicket 1.5 ?

Comment: I want to override certain keys on the application. The keys are already provided in classpath properties, but these need to be adjusted through a external property file. For example it would be enough to use the applicaton servers property files in order to do so.

Comment: What is `applicaton servers property files` ? There is no specification for this, so every web server does something proprietary. Just add custom IStringResourceLoader as explained in the linked SO answer

Answer (score 0):

i18n in Wicket 1.5 (and 6.x, 7.x as well) is the same as in 1.4.